# I need to convert this nested for loop for 3 variables into n variables

Tags: matlab

This is the program where I use the variable `Pesos` when `Nobj=3`. Here I use 3 nested `for` loops to compute `Pesos`, but how should I change the code so that it can handle `Nobj=n`?

```
Nobj=3;
Card=10;
delta1=1/(Card-1);
alpha1=0:delta1:1;
    k=0;
    Pesos=zeros(Card^Nobj,Nobj);
    for i=1:size(alpha1,2)
        for ii=1:size(alpha1,2)
            for iii=1:size(alpha1,2)
                k=k+1;
                Pesos(k,:)=[alpha1(i) alpha1(ii) alpha1(iii)];
                if sum(Pesos(k,:))>0
                    Pesos(k,:)=Pesos(k,:)/sum(Pesos(k,:));
                else
                    Pesos(k,:)=[0 0 1];
                end
            end
        end
    end
```

Comment: `sum(Pesos(k,:))` is *always* going to be larger than zero, because `all(alpha1 > 0)`

Comment: The first row will not be >0. Because all elements are 0

Answer (score 3):

Vectorize it by using [`ndgrid`](https://nl.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/ndgrid.html):

```
% Parameters
N    = 3;
Card = 10;

% Generate regularly-spaced gridded data of identical 
% ranges along N dimensions
alpha1 = linspace(0, 1, Card);       
[Pesos{1:N}] = ndgrid(alpha1);

% Expand and concatenate horizontally
Pesos = cellfun(@(x)x(:), Pesos(N:-1:1), 'UniformOutput', false);    
Pesos = [Pesos{:}];

% Divide by the row sums
Pesos = bsxfun(@rdivide, Pesos, sum(Pesos,2));

% or 
%
% Pesos = Pesos ./ sum(Pesos,2);
%
% if you're on R2016b or later.
```